# Are there any 3rd level spells a Lore Bard could pick at 6th character level to provide food and water to the party?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard, food-and-drink

Just as the title says. I play a Bard, College of Lore. At 6th character level I will be able to pick up two spells, of up to 3rd spell level, from any class. I know we will be on the long-term adventure with no easy way to get food and drinks.  Goodberries could make it much easier for us, but I do not want to "waste" a 3rd level spell known for a 1st level spell if there is something of more power available to me.

Preference is for material from *Player's Handbook* and *Xanathar's Guide To Everything* as it is automatically allowed.  If there are multiple spells that meet the requirement, the one with the widest utility wins. If there are none, the highest level and biggest utility are the factor.

Comment: I'll leave the question without accepted answer for now because I still hope there are more creative options.

Answer (score 26):

The cleric and paladin spell [Create Food and Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-food-and-water)
Unless your party has more than 15 humanoid equivalents, or more than 5 steed equivalents

> You create 45 pounds of food and 30 gallons of water on the ground or
> in containers within range,  enough to sustain up to fifteen humanoids
> or five steeds for 24 hours. The food is bland but nourishing, and
> spoils if uneaten after 24 hours. The  water is clean and doesn’t go
> bad.

That spell should cover your needs, and is the maximum level that you can gain for your bard's level.

Comment: While this is a very simple question and you've got a clear answer, a little more than not even a full sentence would improve your answer :)

Comment: @NautArch Was just about to say that. Technically a correct answer, but very brief. We could use some meat on these bones.

Comment: The question now is - **How could I not see that**. Big +1

Comment: @Mołot That's a separate question. 

Comment: i reread the question like, 5 times because i thought i was missing something!

Comment: And you don't even need to cast it daily necessarily. If you dont have steeds  and are like a 5 people party, it's more than enough food for two days if you cast it once for lunch and eat next days lunch a bit earlier